# LESS pseudo class with arguments

Tags: css, less

I need to construct the following css, using less. But unfortunately the LESS doesn't seem to compile.

Required CSS

```
.container .wrap > div:nth-child(4){
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

LESS

```
.container {
    .wrap {
        > div:nth-child(4) {
            pointer-events: none;
         }
    }
}
```

I am new to LESS and any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does LESS say when you try and compile? It should give you a hint.

Comment: Most likely you're using some outdated Less compiler as your example is actually valid and compiles fine with the reference Less implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.container {
    .wrap {
        & > div:nth-child(4) {
            pointer-events:none;
        }
    }
}
```

So this is clear:

The '&' sign, when used inside a selector definition means 'refer to the parent of the rule that is currently being defined.'  So in this case, it refers to the '.wrap'.